# Pass dynamic XLS file path to Drools rule engine

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine

I am working on the Drools rule engine, and in that, I wanted to pass the file path as dynamically as per the condition. Does anyone have an idea about it? I am attaching a piece of code for reference.

```
private KieFileSystem getKieFileSystem() {
    KieFileSystem fileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
    List<String> rules = Arrays.asList(ruleEngineUrl);
    for (String rule : rules) {
        fileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource(rule));
    }
    return fileSystem;

}
```

In the above code, I wanted to set the ruleEngineUrl dynamically.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution,
what you can do, you can simply pass parameters to getKieFileSystem(String URL). And this will work as your dynamic URL.